# Display a list of values on click with React

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner with React and I am trying to display a list of books, publishers and authors on my page.

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { NavItem } from './components/NavItem';
import  { ListItems }  from './components/ListItems';
import { books } from './books';


class Container extends React.Component {
    tabs = [
        'Authors', 'Publishers' , 'Books'
    ];

    
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            active: '',
        }

    }
    addActiveClass (activeTab){
        return () => {
            this.setState({ active: activeTab});
        }
    };

    
    render() {
        
        const authorList = books.map((book) => {
            return {
                id: book.title,
                label: book.authors
            }
        })
        const publisherList = books.map((book) => {
            return {
                id: book.title,
                label: book.publisher
            }
        })
        const bookList = books.map((book) => {
            return {
                id: book.title,
                label: book.title
            }
        })
        
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className='header'>Library Overview</h1>
                <div>
                    <nav className='NavbarItems'>
                        <ul className='list'>
                            {this.tabs.map(activeTab => (
                                <NavItem
                                    key={activeTab} 
                                    title={activeTab}
                                    active={this.state.active === activeTab}
                                    onClick={this.addActiveClass(activeTab)}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ListItems 
                        items={authorList,publisherList,bookList}
                    />
                    
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Container/>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

And my two components
NavItem.jsx

```
export class NavItem extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render () {
        return(
            <li className='list__item'>
                <a 
                    className={`list-item__link js-tab-name ${this.props.active ? 'active' : null}`}  
                    onClick={(this.props.onClick)} 
                    href='#'
                >
                    {this.props.title}
                </a>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

and ListItems.jsx

```
export const ListItems = (props) => {
  const items = props.items;
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item) => 
      <div 
          className='list__app'
          key={item.id}
      >
        {item.label}
      </div>
    )}
    </>
    
  );
}
```

My book array looks like this:

```
export const books = [{
    title: 'How to win friends and influence people',
    authors: ['Dale Carnegie'],
    publisher: 'Pocket Books',
    year: '1936'
  }, {
    title: 'Management: tasks, responsibilities, practices',
    authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'],
    publisher: 'Harper Business',
    year: '1985'
  }, {
    title: 'Strength finder 2.0',
    authors: ['Tom Rath'],
    publisher: 'Gallup Press',
    year: '2007'
  }, {
    title: 'In search of excellence: Lessons from America\'s best-run companies',
    authors: ['Thomas Peters', ' Robert H. Waterman'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1982'
  }, {
    title: 'Built to last: Successful habits of visionary companies',
    authors: ['James C. Collins', 'Jerry I. Porras'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1994'
  }, {
    title: 'Reengineering the corporation: A manifesto for business revolution',
    authors: ['Michael Hammer', 'James A. Champy'],
    publisher: 'Harper Collins',
    year: '1993'
  }, {
    title: 'Competitive advantage: Creating and sustaining superior performance',
    authors: ['Michael E. Porter'],
    publisher: 'Free Press',
    year: '1998'
  }, {
    title: 'Crossing the chasm: Marketing and selling technology products to mainstream customers',
    authors: ['Geoffrey A. Moore', 'Regis McKenna'],
    publisher: 'Pocket Books',
    year: '1936'
  }, {
    title: 'The innovator\'s dilemma: When new technologies cause great firms to fail',
    authors: ['Clayton M. Christensen'],
    publisher: 'Harvard Business School Press',
    year: '1997'
  }, {
    title: 'The Essential Drucker',
    authors: ['Peter F. Drucker'],
    publisher: 'Harper Business',
    year: '2001'
  }];
```

Currently I am trying to have the page display on click a list of items corresponding to the equivalent Nav bar tab, so when the Authors tab button is clicked, the author of each book should be displayed, likewise when clicking the Publishers and Books tab, however it's only displaying the last set of items, which is the books one at the moment.
How can I tackle this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You give 3 arrays to the props items, but only the last one will be taken into consideration.

```
<ListItems items={authorList,publisherList,bookList}/>
```

you can create another array and push all in.
you can use spread syntax **"..."**

```
<ListItems items={[ ...authorList,...publisherList,...bookList]}/>
```

Too, do not declare a variable in the scop of the class but outside the class or directly in a method, constructor, componentDidMount ect...

> tabs = [
> 'Authors', 'Publishers' , 'Books'
> ];

You can use Button for your component instead of A

> The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md (jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid)

---

You need to learn  to work without a class

Now we develop in React mainly using functions with hooks to interact with component life events.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will alter my code as per your suggestion, however the click functionality is still not working. I want to display the authors when clicking the authors tab, the  titles when clicking the books tab and so on. If i resolve the errors, won't your suggestion show all the lists on the page?

Comment: try this 

onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(activeTab)}

and in NavItem

 onClick={() =>{ this.props.onClick(); }}